# How to make "universal" redirects of errors with .htaccess on html site

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make my .htaccess "universal". 
The site, on local, è `localhost/example`, .htaccess and error.html are 
 in `localhost/example`
My .htaccess is set up to use links without an extension, implicitly adding .html. 
Unfortunately I got stuck on the error redirects: 
I set

> ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/example/errore

and it works but, when I change

> it to ErrorDocument 404 /error

to make it universal it doesn't work.
According to the indications that I found the bar / refers to the root of the site.
I also tried to disable the info on the path (`AcceptPathInfo Off`) but it didn't work.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/example/errore
```

In this case, you specified a full, absolute URL (which should *not* be done - that causes an *external* redirect, so there will not be a proper 404 status code for the originally requested URL) - your URL rewriting to automatically add the correct file suffix works on that, because the client makes a *new, second* request for this URL.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error
```

`/error` here is a “local” URL - and that does not get send through your rewriting, because it gets handled only internally, so it doesn’t find the file, because the suffix is missing.

You need to specify the proper, full file name here.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

Comment: Tahnks but unfortunately it doesn't work, it returns the following error: 
<<"The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request.">>

It seems that in addition to not finding the requested URL you won't even find the error.html file.

Comment: Where exactly is the file located? If it is in a folder `example`, as the URL you had shown first suggests, then you need to use `ErrorDocument 404 /example/error.html`

Comment: sorry I didn't specify. I also correct the text of the question.

Example is the site root.
.htaccess and error.html are in the root.

Comment: If you are calling `http://localhost/example`, then `example` is not the root, it is a folder _inside_ the root. Your description is confusing. So where is the error.html located now - in what _you_ call root, or the actual root?

Comment: I apologize and thank you for your patience.
`error.html` is located in `localhost/example`
I consider root of the localhost/example site even if the true root is localhost  because I always develop in localhost subfolders.

Comment: So you can call `http://localhost/example/error.html` directly then? Then `ErrorDocument 404 /example/error.html` should work, if your .htaccess is really on the root level (_actual_ root), above in your question you’re currently still saying otherwise.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply.
`.htaccess` and `error.html` are both in `localhost/example`.
Example is the folder of the site I am developing and all the contents of it are in here, so I call it the site root (is it wrong?).

Comment: Usually one would mean just what `http://localhost/` points to, when talking about the root of the website `localhost`. This directly ties into stuff like the DOCUMENT_ROOT, which is an important variable from the server/vhost configuration, that is used in a lot of places.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification (I am very inexperienced), I have again corrected the question.
Now, with `localhost/example/error.html`, it works. Being new to domes on stackoverflow I ask: is it ok so I have to do something special?